# Can threejs do this?

Tags: three.js

I have a **large mesh** (millions of faces) and need to selectively **change material on part of it** (there are tens of thousands of those parts). Various parts of the large mesh have different materials (using `MeshFaceMaterial`).

I can't change the `materialIndex` (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468906/three-js-updating-geometry-face-materialindex))
but can't use the suggested solution either (having material for each part) - tens of thousands of materials kills performance as surely as having tens of thousands of objects (at least in my experiments it does).

Changing the geometry is not the solution either since it is much too slow.

Is this a limitation of threejs or am I missing some way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody interested... the only way to accomplish the effect I described above (as far as I know) are shaders + custom attributes.