# How to get closest faces of CubeGeometry with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

For the purposes of this question, I have a demo site running here, which has the code I am working with:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31495717/cubemaker/index.html

I have tried to color the faces of a `CubeGeometry` on the basis of the following calculation:

- Calculate a `Vector3` as the difference between the camera position and a vertex of a cube face
- Calculate the dot product between this vector and each cube face normal

If the sign of the dot product is positive, I color that cube face red and its opposing cube face blue. If the sign is negative, I color the cube face green and the opposing cube face yellow.

By verifying how faces are colored in the rendering, I can verify that my calculation tells me which face indices represent the faces that are closest.

Here is the relevant code I am using in my `render()` function (also available via the demo site):

```
for (var cube_face_idx = 0; cube_face_idx < cube.geometry.faces.length; cube_face_idx++) {
    var face = cube.geometry.faces[cube_face_idx];
    var face_to_camera = new THREE.Vector3();
    face_to_camera.copy(camera.position);
    face_to_camera.sub(cube.geometry.vertices[face.a]);
    var dp = face.normal.dot(face_to_camera);
    if (dp > 0) {
        cube.geometry.faces[cube_face_idx].materialIndex = 0; // red material
        cube.geometry.faces[(cube_face_idx + 6) % 12].materialIndex = 1; // blue material
    }
    else {
        cube.geometry.faces[cube_face_idx].materialIndex = 2; // green material
        cube.geometry.faces[(cube_face_idx + 6) % 12].materialIndex = 3; // yellow material
    }
}
```

The problems I am running into are these:

1. When I rotate the cube, I am rotating the camera, and so the coloring of the cube faces should also be changed, so that the camera always sees the same cube face colors relative to the camera's new position. However, the coloring follows the face as the cube is rotated.
2. The coloring of red and blue faces should be opposite within the cube. Likewise. the coloring of green and yellow faces should be opposite within the cube. However, some green and yellow faces are adjacent. Additionally, red and blue faces are adjacent and not opposite. As the cube is rotated counter-clockwise around the y-axis, a blue face is opposite a yellow face. This should not happen.

My goal is to calculate the three closest faces of the cube, so that I can get their vertices and draw axes.

I am hoping with the above calculation to determine which faces are closest at any given camera position. However, the coloring follows the faces as the cube is rotated, so I cannot know from this approach which faces are closest.

Based on the coloring pattern showing up on adjacent faces, I think my indexing of cube faces is also incorrect.

How might I fix my calculation step to address the two problems and correctly identify the faces closest to the camera?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468906/three-js-updating-geometry-face-materialindex/12469179#12469179

Comment: I don't see how that helps, can you explain?

Comment: Are you attempting to change `materialIndex` in the render loop?

Comment: I'm attempting to calculate the closest faces to the camera, using the material index as a visual indicator. I'm happy to use whatever method works.

Comment: Are you attempting to change `materialIndex` in the render loop?