# how to render partially semi-transparent meshes?

Tags: 3d, three.js, transparency

the issue i am having is when i have a mesh where only some of the faces of that mesh should be semi-transparent while the rest of of the object should be opaque. Anyone got any idea on how i should solve this issue?

Here is some more description of the issue for clarity: In our viewer we merge multiple meshes together if they have the same material properties.

Then if the user clicks on the merged object we find the surface that was clicked and the original id of the object of that face. Then we only highlight the faces for that object with our own custom shaders.

one object selected
[image: one object selected]

Now the issue is that if we make the material transparent(so the selected part is semi-transparent) then the whole merged mesh is transparent and the opaque part of the model is rendered as transparent.

You can see some of the visual issues in this picture:

visual issues for partially transparent object
[image: visual issues for partially transparent object]

I had multiple ideas on how we could solve this, but they all would increase the memory consumption and complexity:

1. discard fragments that should be transparent then create a new mesh with the selected faces and transparent materials.
2. Create a copy of the whole merged mesh that is transparent and then only render the selected objects faces in the transparent object and discard the fragments in the original non-transparent mesh.

Anyone got a better idea ?

using three r84.

Comment: do you have `.transparent = true` for all the boxes?

Comment: all the boxes are one mesh in this example so by setting the material to transparent so i can show some faces transparent will make it so all the boxes are transparent.

Comment: Using depth peeling you could achieve what you want, but I think three.js does not implement it natively. Your best strategy I think, is to divide your "grouped mesh" into several meshs and treat each "box" independently. Transparency is never a trivial problem in 3D rendering.

Comment: The problem is that we merge together objects for improved performance when navigating in the viewer. When we select multiple objects or make large part of the model transparent we would have to do split up the mesh into smaller meshes on the fly and it greatly increases how many rendering calls we have to do. But it seems there is no easy fix for this and the solution must be somewhat complex.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get why you don't want to use separated box meshes, as it would be easier to manage transparency of each one.

But if you want to use a single geometry, I came up with an approach of using two materials, `.materialIndex` and a dynamic geometry. The approach relies on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12469179/4045502).

```
var materials = [
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: "white" }),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: "white", transparent: true, opacity: 0.5})
];

. . .

var cloneGeom = new THREE.Geometry();

var oldBoxIndex = 0;

function setBoxTransparent(boxIndex) {
  cloneGeom = mesh.geometry.clone();
  setBoxMaterial(oldBoxIndex, 0);
  setBoxMaterial(boxIndex, 1);
  mesh.geometry.dispose();
  mesh.geometry = cloneGeom;
  oldBoxIndex = boxIndex;
}

function setBoxMaterial(boxIndex, materialIndex) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    cloneGeom.faces[12 * boxIndex + i].materialIndex = materialIndex;
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/bn5kgyso/) example r87.

Comment: Because separated box meshes would mean that instead of having 1 mesh = 1 draw call you would have 50k boxes = 50 000 draw calls that would mean really low FPS, or am i misunderstanding what you mean ? Also i'm using BufferGeometry and customShaders so i would have to fit it to use that. Even with using materialIndex it would increase the number of render calls since each group is called once if i understood the render function correctly, but it would only be only double render calls for selected objects.  Thanks for taking your time and ill take closer look to see if using groups could work!

Comment: You're welcome ) But you should've mentioned about over 50k boxes (or complexity of the scene) and custom shaders in your question ) Instead, you show a picture with just 256 boxes, which are not such a big deal to render )

Comment: Yea you are right about that :) I used the boxes for easily showing the concept, but the real application of it is large CAD-models.