# three.js: How to add materials array to octahedron geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to add multiple materials to a `THREE.OctahedronGeometry`. This works fine for box objects, but for `THREE.OctahedronGeometry` I just get the first material on all faces. How can I get a different material on each face?

```
        var geometry = new THREE.OctahedronGeometry(1, 0);

        var materials = [
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x050505, dithering: true } ),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xeeeeee, dithering: true } ),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x060606, dithering: true } ),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xeeeeee, dithering: true } ),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x050505, dithering: true } ),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xeeeeee, dithering: true } ),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x070707, dithering: true } ),
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xeeeeee, dithering: true } )
        ];

        var someMesh = new THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry , materials );

        someMesh.castShadow = true; //default is false
        someMesh.receiveShadow = true; //default
        scene.add( someMesh );
```

Comment: var someMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials ); 
does not work either!

Answer (score 3):

You can add support for multi-materials to any `THREE.BufferGeometry` by specifying groups. Use a pattern like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.OctahedronBufferGeometry( 5, 0 );

geometry.clearGroups(); // just in case
geometry.addGroup( 0, 3, 0 ); // first 3 vertices use material 0
geometry.addGroup( 3, 3, 1 ); // next 3 vertices use material 1
geometry.addGroup( 6, Infinity, 2 ); // remaining vertices use material 2

var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } ),
];


var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
scene.add( mesh );
```

If you must use `THREE.Geometry`, you can add support for multi-materials by specifying a material index for each face. See [three.js updating geometry face materialindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468906/three-js-updating-geometry-face-materialindex/12469179#12469179).

If all you want to do is have a different color on each face, it is much more efficient to specify face-colors or vertex colors and render the entire geometry with a single material. (But that is a separate issue.)

three.js r.89

Comment: How can I learn more about vertex lists such as geometry.addGroup( 6, Infinity, 2 ); ?

Comment: Where can I learn more about specifying face-colors or vertex colors?

Comment: For example: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry and https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors