# Multiple textures in shader material

Tags: three.js, textures

I have created 3d terrain model with three js. Now I'm facing with texturing problem. Is there any possibility to add 2 or even more textures to one geometry using shader material?  What I mean is example how to attach multiple textures to geometry next to each other.

Comment: What specific issues are you having? Do you have no idea where to start?

Comment: Yes, exactly no idea how to start. When I add texture it fills automatically whole geometry. How to cover for example half of geometry and use another texure to cover rest?

Comment: @user12270536 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880715/texture-splatting-with-three-js. For a completely different approach to your problem see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48733733/1461008.

Comment: If I understood in one example result is adding texture base on terrain elevation and other adding texutre to specific grometry single face. Is not what I need. To be clear I want to attach satellite photos (like google maps) using map tiles to generated terrain. Here's my terrain demo http://dpruciak.nazwa.pl/tatry/